# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" while accessing JSON from external URL

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, web, jsonp

I am trying to access JSON data from an external URL.

I am using **JSONP** and here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://myurl.com',
dataType: 'JSONP',
jsonpCallback: 'callback',
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}});
```

The status code is 200, even I can see the JSON from that URL but I am getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

and unable to work with that JSON data

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: As the **error** states, the received JSON is invalid. If you generate that JSON yourself, use a proper function for encoding the JSON and feed it actual objects or arrays. Don't attempt to stitch it up yourself. If you don't generate that JSON yourself, you need to inform whoever is responsible for that API it's borked and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: The JSON  is absolutely fine .

Comment: may you please write json resonse

Comment: What you believe regarding that JSON contradicts with what the manufacturers of the browser you are using believe. I'm a bit biased. Based on experience, I tend to assume they are right and you are wrong, but feel free to inform them of their erroneous implementation of JSON parser if you are absolutely sure you are right.

Comment: Could you also include your `callback()` function?

Comment: function callback(data){
console.log(data);
}

Comment: The URL you're calling is probably not supporting JSONP. Does it work with just JSON as the data type?

Comment: When the JSON is valid, it [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/aq5kydej/).